# Counting from deferent function for()

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, loops

i have some problem with this work, i plan to create a function to compute from two for () functions. if you ask why I have to make 2 functions to calculate it, it is because the calculated data is taken from different json data, and I need to loops each of those data to get dynamic sum row.

**my first function for()**

```js
jml_lls_doktor = [
    {
        "t20181": {
            "jum": 5090 //get it jum
        }
    },
    {
        "t20191": {
            "jum": 3386
        }
    },
    {
        "t20201": {
            "jum": 1826
        }
    }
];

let result_doktor = [];
      let i = 0;
      if(jml_lls_doktor){
        for(var key in jml_lls_doktor){
          result_doktor[i]={
            "jumlah_doktor_hitung" : Object.keys(jml_lls_doktor[key]).map((keys, i9)=>
              jml_lls_doktor[key][keys]
            )
          } 
        i++;
        }
      }
      
      console.log(result_doktor);
```

**and this my second function for**

```js
let jml_ipk3 = [
    {
        "2018": {
            "ipk2": "null",
            "ipk3": "null"
        }
    },
    {
        "2019": {
            "ipk2": 4,
            "ipk3": 4
        }
    },
    {
        "2020": {
            "ipk2": "null",
            "ipk3": "null"
        }
    }
];
      let result_ipk3 = [];
      let i2 = 0;
      if(jml_ipk3){
        for(var key in jml_ipk3){
          result_ipk3[i2]={
          "ipk3" : Object.keys(jml_ipk3[key]).map((keys, i9)=>
                    jml_ipk3[key][keys].ipk3
            )
          } 
          i2++;
        }
      }
      console.log(result_ipk3);
```

How i count

> (result_ipk3/result_doktor)*100

Comment: Are you wanting the final result of `(result_ipk3/result_doktor)*100` to be an array of each `result_ipk3/result_doktor` pair from your loops' final results (currently arrays), or do you want to reduce both to a single value before computing `result_ipk3/result_doktor`?

Comment: Also, your second loop only retrieves the value of `ipk3` and ignores `ipk2`. Is that intentional?

Comment: I want to count two parts into one value (result_ipk3/result_doktor)*100

i just took the value from ipk3 sir,

Comment: could you please comment an example of what the final outcome should be, and I can come up with a function that achieves that? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let count = [];
  let i = 0;
  for(var key in jml_lls_doktor, jml_ipk3 ){
    count [i]={
      "ipk3" : Object.keys(jml_lls_doktor[key]).map((keys, i9)=>
                parseInt(jml_lls_doktor[key][keys].ipk3)
              ),
      "aktif" : Object.keys(jml_lls_doktor_aktif[key]).map((keys, i9)=>
                parseInt(jml_lls_doktor_aktif[key][keys].jum)
                )
    }
    i_count_doktor++;
  }
///On rendering reactjs
{
                      count_doktor.map((list,i)=>
                      <td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
                        {String(list.ipk3/list.aktif*100).slice(0,4)}%
                      </td>
                      )
                    }
```